# Exclude specific element by id on querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I try get length of an array from:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea');
alert(Object.keys(arr).length);//19
```

Inside that array i have to exclude 4 elements, being 2 `input type="hidden"`, and 2 with specif `id's`, so i try use `:not selector`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea,input:not[type="hidden",input:not[id="input_up_img_perfil"],input:not[id="sub_img_perfil"],');
alert(Object.keys(arr).length);//19
```

What is the right sintax for that query?

Comment: `input:not('[type=hidden]')`, you're missing the parentheses of the negation (the [`:not()`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:not)) operator, as well as the closing `]` character that should appear after the first `"hidden"`.

Comment: Negative are wellcome, pls if possible, try any tip to made that question better!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select,input:not([type="hidden"]):not(#input_up_img_perfil):not(#sub_img_perfil),textarea');
```

It should work pretty fine ;)

It is actually pretty simple: first, you need to add parenthesis to the `:not` operator. Then, you need to think about the proper CSS query to select what you need.

Example that will **not** work:

```
'input:not([type="hidden"]),input:not(#input_up_img_perfil),input:not(#sub_img_perfil)'
```

because you have actually three queries and the result will be merged at the end, since `input:not(#input_up_img_perfil)` has no constraint on the hidden fields, you'll get them in the result even though you set `input:not([type="hidden"])`.

That's why you need to do the following:

```
'input:not([type="hidden"]):not(#input_up_img_perfil):not(#sub_img_perfil)'
```

Here, you have only one query on the input tag, with three constraints!

Hope this is clear ;)

Comment: Perfetct, tkssss!

Comment: Thanks! (Original comment removed, as this will be shortly.)

Answer (score 2):

For Example

```
<input class="test">
<input class="test asd">
```

Try something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span.test:not(.asd)');
```

Instead of:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea,input:not[type="hidden",input:not[id="input_up_img_perfil"],input:not[id="sub_img_perfil"],');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the collection of nodes to an array, and then use  `Array#filter` to filter out the non-required elements:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select,input,textarea'))
  .filter(item => item.type !== 'hidden' || item.id !== 'input_up_img_perfil' || item.id !== 'sub_img_perfil');
```

Comment: tks for atention, i need use `exclude element with :not selector` way, you know how?